# Groupby type and count each element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, count

I have this dataframe `df`, which includes `name` and `type` columns:

```
name   type
Jay    c1
Rand   c2
Hano   c3
Jay    c1
Jay    c2
Rand   c2
Roger  c1
Roger  c1
Roger  c3
```

The output should be like that (for each of the type, how many each name; inserted as a new column):

```
name   type   count
Jay    c1     2
Jay    c2     1
Rand   c2     2
Hano   c3     1
Roger  c1     2
Roger  c3     1
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['name','type']).size().reset_index(name='count')`?

Comment: Yes, that's works with me; thanks! @QuangHoang